# What NSString compare method call is equivalent to a CFStringCompare function call?

Tags: cocoa, comparison, nsstring, macos-carbon, cfstring

I am converting some old carbon code to Cocoa and need to use a comparison function that will return the same result as the one in carbon.

I am calling:

```
CFStringCompare( stringA, stringB, kCFCompareCaseInsensitive | kCFCompareDiacriticInsensitive | kCFCompareNumerically );
```

Now, if stringA & stringB were NSString's and I wanted to compare them using a NSString method, which one, with what options (if any), would return the same result as the CFStringCompare function above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer appears to be:

```
NSStringCompareOptions  compareOptions = NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSNumericSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch;

result = [stringA compare:stringB options:compareOptions];
```

Answer (score -1):

[string1 isEqualToString:string2];

[string1 caseSensitiveCompare:string2];

and so on.

goto the NSString class reference for more information

Comment: I don't believe this is true. The documentation says: 'So, for instance, “Ö” represented as the composed character sequence “O” and umlaut would not compare equal to “Ö” represented as one Unicode character.' The kCFCompareDiacriticInsensitive option, I am pretty sure, would say those two characters are equal.

Comment: Right, there are many methods with various options. Which one matches the CFStringCompare function in the question.

Comment: Then cast your NSString to a CFString and go from there